# Confidence interval for continuous uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, method-of-moments

If X is a random variable from the uniform distribution on the interval [0,θ], how would one construct a 95% confidence interval for the method of moments estimator of θ?

I have found that [image]

and also its asymptotic distribution
[image]

but I do not understand how to find a confidence interval for it. I know that I have to use the central limit theorem but I do not know how to apply it in this case.

Comment: Yes, I saw this post. But I do not understand how chi-square is connected to the interval. can you suggest anything that would be helpful in understanding mentioned part?

Comment: If this is so, specify that part that you couldn't understand (or in fact you could leave a comment there once you have sufficient reputation).